# Can't find installed Office 2013 Home and business with MsiEnumProducts

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-installer, ms-office, office-2013

I use MsiEnumProducts() to find all installed MS Office products and check their versions. If I have an Office 2013 Professional Plus edition, it works correctly. I receive a full list of installed office products, like word, excel, outlook, etc, with correct product code GUIDs. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2786054

The GUIDs look like this:

- Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013 - {90150000-0011-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}
- Microsoft Word MUI (English) 2013 - {90150000-001B-0409-1000-0000000FF1CE}

But if I have Home and business edition on PC, the MsiEnumProducts() doesn't find installed Office. The only installed office products, that the function provides, are:

- Office 15 Click-to-Run Extensibility Component - {90150000-008C-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}
- Office 15 Click-to-Run Localization Component -
  {90150000-008C-0407-1000-0000000FF1CE}
- Office 15 Click-to-Run Licensing Component -
  {90150000-007E-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}

But the Office 2013 Home and business edition GUIDs should look like this {90150000-**0013**-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}.

I have Win 8.1 x64, Office x64, program is built both under Win32 and x64.

What do you think about the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click to run is a technique Microsoft uses to virtualize and stream office to end users without actually "installing" it.  There's no installed product information to find.

Comment: Thanks. And can you tell, how to get Office products, installed using click-to-run ? Are there any API methods, or separate sdk ?

Comment: This might be what you are looking for. I don't have access to a license of Office C2R and I'm not a big fan anyways so it's not worth my time to set it up in a lab and confirm. http://csi-windows.com/blog/all/77-office-365/429-enumerating-click-to-run-installed-products-for-office-365-proplus-2013-

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to find some solution.