# Uninstall a program installed via MSI - Only know the install location

Tags: windows-installer, uninstallation

I know the install location of a program installed via a MSI. I want to write a script that will remove it. I do not know the GUID as it changes often. How do I accomplish this goal?

I checked out the [command line options](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/314881) for the installer tool, but I didn't see anything that would allow me to specify the install location to select a product.

Comment: Assuming you can write some code for this, you could try the techniques I covered [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37591273/89999).

Answer (score 3):

You will need to find the UpgradeCode (look in the installation log file for the property).

From there, use [MsiEnumRelatedProducts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370103(v=vs.85).aspx) to iterate over all the instances of the product. The vast majority of products don't support multi-instance installations, so there should only be one product code returned in the buffer.

Once you know the ProductCode, you can `msiexec /x {PRODUCT-GUID}` to your heart's content.

If you're not comfortable with C++, you can find different implementations of `MsiEnumRelatedProducts` in PowerShell extensions and C# libraries, to name a few.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the Product code like this: [How can I find the product GUID of an installed MSI setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937568/how-can-i-find-the-product-guid-of-an-installed-msi-setup/29937569) and invoke the uninstall using: **msiexec.exe /x {product-guid-here**}

There are many ways to uninstall an MSI file, here are 13 different ways: [Uninstalling an MSI file from the command line without using msiexec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec/1055933#1055933). **Check out section 5** for a way to uninstall by product name using PowerShell.

Here is a VBScript that uninstalls by reading the product details from the registry (resurrected from WayBack): https://web.archive.org/web/20160318175702/http://www.symantec.com:80/connect/downloads/uninstall-application-using-guid-registry